# Why ParallelEvaluate[x = 0; {$KernelID, Dynamic[x]}] returns {{1,x},{2,x}}?

Tags: dynamic, parallelization

I'd expect that

```
ParallelEvaluate[x = 0; {$KernelID, Dynamic[x]}]
```

returns `{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}`, and that if in a parallel computation the value of `x` changes in a kernel, it would be updated.

Instead the above line executes to `{{1,x},{2,x}}`, where for some reason `x` is unevaluated. Can someone explain this?

PS. In my PC I had two available kernels when I tested this. Of course the number of kernels will change the length of the lists.

Comment: Put `SetSharedVariable[x];` before the line, so that the definition of `x` can be passed among the different kernels.

Comment: What is the reason for using `Dynamic` then?  You can do `ParallelEvaluate[x = RandomReal[]; {$KernelID, x}]` and it works as I would expect

Comment: @JasonB I am doing some computations in each kernel after this, and I want to monitor the value of `x` in each kernel during the computations.

Comment: ahhh, so from what I read `Dynamic` has the attribute `HoldFirst` so you have to use `With[{x = x}, Dynamic[x]]` instead of `Dynamic[x]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Responding to the OP's comment, here is a way to monitor subkernel progress.

```
(* Clear variables *)
ToExpression["x" <> ToString[#], StandardForm, Clear] & /@ 
  ParallelEvaluate[$KernelID, Kernels[]];

(* Monitor *)
With[{varnames = "x" <> ToString[#] & /@ ParallelEvaluate[$KernelID, Kernels[]]},
 With[{vars = ToExpression@varnames},
  SetSharedVariable[vars];
  Dynamic@Grid[{varnames, vars}]
  ]]

(* Computation *)
ParallelEvaluate[
 ToExpression[
  "x" <> ToString@ $KernelID <> "=0"];              (* initialize monitor $*)
 Do[
  Pause[RandomReal[]];                              (* compute next step *)
  ToExpression["x" <> ToString@$KernelID <> "++"],  (* update monitor *)
  {10}]]
```

During computation, which is fun to watch:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

After completion:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One seems to need to use a different symbol for each subkernel.  Updating a single shared variable leads to synchronization issues.

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you are asking about,

```
ParallelEvaluate[x = 0; {$KernelID, With[{x = x}, Dynamic[x]]}]
(*{{1,0},{2,0},{3,0},{4,0}}*)
```

But it negates the point of having `Dynamic` since it won't update.  Need to see the full code to see how you want to use it in the end.